# Facebook open graph protocol

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

I would like to ask how to add data with links after the description to a Facebook post, what meta tags i should use to have such result like image below

http://alternative-spaces.com/UPDATE/screen_shots/GraphProtocol.png

Here is my code

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Exciting views and amazing floor plans"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mysite.com/"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="sdfsfsd http://mysite.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://somagrand.com/images/fb_icon.jpg" />

<meta property="og:site_name" content="content"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="company" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="229103737100322"/>
<meta property="og:latitude" content="33.8164994"/>
<meta property="og:longitude" content="-116.5469377"/>
<meta property="og:street-address" content="1160 Mission St."/>
<meta property="og:locality" content="San Francisco"/>
<meta property="og:region" content="CA"/>
<meta property="og:postal-code" content="94103"/>
<meta property="og:country-name" content="USA"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That post wasnt made by liking a page on that site and therefore wont be concerned with open graph tags. It was done through the legacy REST API action `stream.publish` - if you go here: http://www.musicolio.com and click the 'share' button at the top you will notice the URL for the popup is something like this (once decoded):

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/stream.publish?action_links=[{"text":"Join Now","href":"http://www.musicolio.com/"}]&api_key=138938132827513&app_id=138938132827513&attachment={"name":"Musicolio","href":"http://www.musicolio.com/","description":"Collaborate on music projects, connect with musicians, find talented musicians, find work in the music industry.","media":[{"type":"image","src":"http://www.musicolio.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/micon.png","href":"http://www.musicolio.com/"}],**"properties":{"Get Discovered":"Monitored by industry executives","Private":"No Spam","Job Boards":"Get work, get paid","Free":"Get connected for free"}**}&display=popup&locale=en_US&next=https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?version=3#cb=f24407dddc7a49a&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.musicolio.com%2Ff1be678fb013a1e&relation=opener&transport=postmessage&frame=f11e216310dbbde&result=%22xxRESULTTOKENxx%22&sdk=joey&target_id=

I've highlighted the part you're interested in. More information on this can be found here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments/

Comment: if i use new facebook library, could open such dialog?

Comment: yes but i dont think you can use the properties attribute, see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/